angular: subscribe changes on a part of a (complex, hierarchical) component input
I'm creating a component that has a rather complex, nested configuration

export type LayerGroup = {
  name: string;
  layers: Array<VectorLayerDefinition | TileLayerDefinition | LayerGroup>;
  kind: 'group';
};

@Component(blabla)
export class MyComponent {
   layerGroup = input<LayerGroup>();
}

That works, and i can create effects that will get executed every time the input changed. But now, in my component, every layer is supposed to have filters. And when a filter changes, i want to update that layer in my view without refreshing everything (that would create flicker)
In other words, i'd like to "subscribe" to layerGroup.layers[0].filter for the first layer and so on. For now, the only possiblity i see is to do a deep diff between the old and the new configuration, and then transforming the diff until i have something useful. That would work, i already found some libraries that implement the diffing. It would be quite some work tho.
So i wonder if there is an easier or better way, maybe leveraging an existing library, since this diffing should be already built in in angular to implement change detection ?

How is layerGroup getting updated?  Signals are supposed to be immutable, so if a filter property is being changed directly on the object then you have a problem.  If you're respecting the immutability, then if the filter changed, layerGroup changed and the view should be updated as well.

the layerGroup is updated as a normal input, so it changes. I can get ngOnChanges and so on (and creating an effect on the layerGroup will also work). The problem however is that i will always get the whole layerGroup structure, which will be 90% identical (there will be only one property that changed somewhere deep down in the structure).
